# Excel: calculate position weighted matrix score

Tags: excel

Now, I used sum(vlookup... for matching each individual letter to the matrix table of letter-score-in fixed position but I wonder is there a better way to calculate this?

For example, first string is ABCD. According to matrix table, A in position 1 is 1 + B position 2 is 6 + C position 3 is 11 + D position 4 is 16

I used `SUM(VLOOKUP(D28,$H$28:$L$31,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(E28,$H$28:$L$31,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(F28,$H$28:$L$31,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G28,$H$28:$L$31,5,FALSE))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The CODE solution is probably the best answer for this particular question.

If there's an implied question of how to look something up in a 2d array, I would do it using this array formula:-

```
=SUM($I$28:$L$31*(D28:G28=$H$28:$H$31))
```

The second part forms a 2d array by matching the letters in the row D28:G28 with letters in the column H28:H31 to give a matrix which looks like this for A,B,C,D:-

```
1,0,0,0
0,1,0,0
0,0,1,0
0,0,0,1
```

and this is multiplied element by element by the 2d array in I28:L31 so that only the elements matching a '1' (1,6,11,16) are non-zero.

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>